# Using 4.7.2 Framework for WPF Project System.NET.HTTP Cannot Be Found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.7.2

I was originally developing a project using the 4.6.1 Framework however one of the Nuget packages I wanted required the new 4.7.2 Framework to be used. As a result, I upgraded my project, which when attempting to run again and send a HTTP request gave me the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, 
Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**********' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

How do I resolve this? (If I downgrade back to 4.6.1 it works, and I've also tried to uninstall and reinstall System.Net while using 4.7.2 Framework)

Comment: I did, I mentioned I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it when I upgraded.

Comment: Did you do a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yep, I can also see that its in references. However I'm still getting this error

Comment: Possibly this may be the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29622

Answer (score 0):

In app.config change:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
```

to

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
```